# JPA: Using @MapKey for an abstract class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have the following structure of 
an abstract superclass A 
and a class Z referring to As sublasses B and C using a map:

```
@Entity
Abstract Class A
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    Integer map_field; <----------------------- Problematic
    ....

@Entity
Class B extends A
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    Integer map_field;
    ....

@Entity
Class C extends A
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    Integer map_field;
    ....

@Entity
Class Z
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name="map_field")
    private Map<Integer,A> a_entities;
```

The problem is that the map_field is based on values of the objects B and C and not on class values of A.

So basically I cannot use the map_field using the @MapKey annotation in class Z as written above. I do not have useful values for the map_field of class A.

Does anyone have hints how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance, Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see your ploblem. Your class A is abstract so there are never instance of it, so they don't need to have any "useful values", and even if, you caould have useless default value of A for example 0 or -1 depending on your case.
You cannot hide the fields of your superclass in B,C as it will mess up with everything. Remove them from B,C and all it work (also the id is redundant as it is already defined in A).
But you should add your inheritance strategy for A, not leave it to a chance (defaults).